# Getting number of new features to be stored in layers using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, editing

In PyQGIS, how can I get the number of features that have been created in a given layer and that are pending to be saved in the layer when "Toggle editing" or "Saving layer edits"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Say that you have a vector layer referenced:

```
lyr = iface.activeLayer()
```

At this point, I assume you start an edit session and digitize some features.

Now you can use the `QgsVectorLayerEditBuffer` class, in this way:

```
if lyr.editBuffer():
    print len( lyr.editBuffer().addedFeatures() ), "features to add!"
```

`addedFeatures` gives you a dictionary of new features that are pending. As you're interested in the count, you can use `len()`.