# QGIS Python variable not updating after new features are inserted

Tags: pyqgis

I have the following script that sets the a feature id automatically after a new feature is digitized.

I added the function inside the project's Macro section inside openProject() function:

[image]

The function is being triggered ok every time I open the project. My problem now is that every new feature I create gets the same id (9707).

It seems like max varibles' value is not being updated after a new feature is added and without "Toggle editing" or "Saving layer edits".

Current code:

```
def openProject():
    from qgis.core import QgsMapLayerRegistry
    import os
    # Set active layer
    #layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
    layer=None
    for lyr in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():
        if lyr.name() == "Pozos":
            layer = lyr
            break
    # Define function to select added feature and add attribute to field "Name"
    def update(featureAdded):
        idx = layer.fieldNameIndex('id')
        layer.changeAttributeValue(featureAdded, idx, layer.maximumValue(idx) +1)
    # Connect "featureAdded" event to "select" function
    layer.featureAdded.connect(update)

def saveProject():
    pass

def closeProject():
    pass
```

Comment: Just a guess but try replacing `max = layer.maximumValue(idx) + 1` with `max = int(layer.maximumValue(idx)) + 1`. Also, you should post the actual code into the question =)

Comment: @Joseph edited the OP with the code

Comment: Have you tried to work with the data provider, as in *layer.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues()*?

Comment: @Joseph tried your solution suggestion and didn't work. Same result, all new points get the same id.

Comment: @BritishSteel Thanks for your suggestion, I am trying your solution, but It is my second day using pyQGIS and I am still a bit lost. What arguments would I need to add in changeAttributeValues? "layer.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues(featureAdded, idx, max)" is not working

Answer (score 4):

After some search I finally found a working solution:
As I saw that `layer.maximumValue(idx)` always kept the same value until I commited changes, I added the number of new elements and that are pending to be commited to this variable. This way I always get serial (autonumeric) number.
Idea taken from [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/194748/qgis-python-getting-number-of-new-features-to-be-stored-in-layers/194759#194759):

```
def openProject():
    from qgis.core import QgsMapLayerRegistry
    import os
    # Set active layer
    #layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
    layer=None
    for lyr in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():
        if lyr.name() == "Pozos":
            layer = lyr
            break
    # Define function to select added feature and add attribute to field "Name"
    def update(featureAdded):
        idx = layer.fieldNameIndex('id')
    if layer.editBuffer():
        layer.changeAttributeValue(featureAdded, idx, layer.maximumValue(idx) + len( lyr.editBuffer().addedFeatures() ))
    # Connect "featureAdded" event to "select" function
    layer.featureAdded.connect(update)
```