# QGIS Python variable not updating properly after layer data is saved

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

This problem is a continuation of [this one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/194753/qgis-python-variable-not-updating-after-new-features-are-inserted)

I am running a little script on OpenProject event that sets the feature id automatically after a new feature is digitized.

Code:

```
def openProject():
from qgis.core import QgsMapLayerRegistry
import os
# Set active layer
#layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
layer=None
for lyr in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():
    if lyr.name() == "Pozos":
        layer = lyr
        break
# Define function to select added feature and add attribute to field "Name"
def update(featureAdded):
    idx = layer.fieldNameIndex('id')
if layer.editBuffer():
    layer.changeAttributeValue(featureAdded, idx, layer.maximumValue(idx) + len( lyr.editBuffer().addedFeatures() ))
# Connect "featureAdded" event to "select" function
layer.featureAdded.connect(update)
```

As I am using the number of addedFeatures in editBuffer to create the new id. I have a big problem: when the user saves the data, the number of addedFeatures in editBuffer is 0 again and the new ids created after saving are then duplicated.

I suppose that a solution for my problem would be to use:

```
layer.changeAttributeValue(featureAdded, idx, layer.maximumValue(idx) +1)
```

instead of:

```
layer.changeAttributeValue(featureAdded, idx, layer.maximumValue(idx) + len( lyr.editBuffer().addedFeatures() ))
```

I tried it, but the second solution gives me the same id all the time. I suppose that layer.maximumValue(idx) returns the max id of the saved features and does not take into account the ones in editBuffer.

Antoher approach would be to reexceute the macro when user saves the data of the layer, but I don't know how to do that.

I need same expert help with this issue...